# AttributeError: 'Command' object has no attribute 'command' in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv("TOKEN")

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=["."],help_command=None)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Ready")


@client.command(invoke_without_command=True)
async def help(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(title="**Help List**",description="Help shows this command",color=discord.Color.blurple())
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)

@help.command()
async def changeprefix(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(title="**Changeprefix**",description=".Changeprefix <newprefix>",color=discord.Color.blurple())
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)

client.run(TOKEN)
```

The error I'm getting:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:/Users/trymk/OneDrive/Documents/python/discord/Help2.py", line 22, in 
@help.command()
AttributeError: 'Command' object has no attribute 'command'

Comment: What did you type to get the error?

Comment: Yeah sorry forgot to mention that. It comes up whenever I start the program. I don't have to type anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cleaner way of doing it.
I suggest at `Line 13` change it to: `async def help(ctx,*,specific=None):`
Change the `help` command as such:

```py
@client.command(invoke_without_command=True)
async def help(ctx,*,specific=None):
    if specific==None:
        embed = discord.Embed(title="**Help List**",description="Help shows this command",color=discord.Color.blurple())
    elif specifc=="changeprefix":
        embed = discord.Embed(title="**Changeprefix**",description=".Changeprefix <newprefix>",color=discord.Color.blurple())
    else:
        embed = discord.Embed(title="**Command Not Found**",color=discord.Color.red())
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

You can then run the command in discord like `.help changeprefix`

You can also expand for other commands by doing another elif

Comment: Thanks man! Sorry for having a shit post, just didn't have the time and energy to post a good explanation of what my problem was, but you understood it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error at `@help.command()` is because your `help` command, the command object, doesn't support or have a method called `command`. You can view a list of attributes and methods on the [documentation for discord.ext.commands here.](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html)

I'm not sure exactly what your question is but I'd suggest trying the answer by **Fishball Nooodles** as I think their answer might resolve your issue.